# When a user click on a submit button - How to wait 1 second before activating it with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, prestashop

I am trying to integrate an API that works everytime a user clicks on a submit button form. This is working, except that the API doesn't have the time to activate because we are directly redirected on another page.

So, I am looking for a way that, when a user clicks on the button… There is a redirect only after 1 or 2 seconds.

I have tried :

```
submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  submitButton.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");

  // Removes disabling after 2 seconds
  window.setTimeout(function() {
      submitButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
  }, 2000);
},false);
```

But as expected, with that function, the button doesn't work at all. 
Logically, I should insert the function that redirect or not the user on the setTimeout function.

Problem is : This is a prestashop website from a client and I doesn't have the name of this function.

If you have any idea… 
Thank you!

P.S: I'm using Google Tag Manager and Jquery doesn't work on it.

Comment: Don't you think that the user have to be redirected just when you finish the API call?

Comment: It is possible ?
I am a beginner in web development, so if you have advice… I take it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `event.preventDefault()` is going to be your friend whichever solution you ultimately go with. That will stop the normal event hooks from firing.

Instead of just marking the button disabled, you need to stop the click event from actually doing what it's supposed to do. Thus, `preventDefault()`.

The following code will block the click from happening 
Something along these lines should work:

```
(function(){
  // set flag to indicate whether we should wait or actually submit
  var delaySubmit = true;
  // get form el
  var form = document.getElementById('#YourFormId');
  form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {

    // if we've already waited the 2 seconds, submit
    if( ! delaySubmit )
      return;

    // otherwise, stop the submission
    e.preventDefault();
    // set the flag for next time
    delaySubmit = false;

    // and resubmit in 2 seconds. 
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        this.submit();
    }, 2000);
  });
})();
```

Comment: I didn't know this function… That's great thank you ! But it looks like the form doesn't redirects correctly now… It doesn't indicates errors (password missing, etc.) and doen't redirects the user on his customer area. :/

Comment: Okay, instead of form.submit() event, I have use button.click() event and it's working. Thank you again. :)

Comment: @Sandra You're welcome! Don't forget to "accept" the answer that solves your problem.